# window.onload function executes on form change

Tags: javascript, onload

The showweeks function executes whenever the form value is changed.  Shouldn't it just execute once onload?

```
function showweeks() {

    if (document.forms["c_form"]["frequency"].value == "daily") {
        document.getElementById("c_dayint").style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("c_dayint").style.backgroundColor = "#aaaaaa";
    }
    return;
}

window.onload = function() {

    showweeks();

    return;
};
```

Comment: Given just this code - yes.

Comment: Thanks..I'll focus on everything else.

Comment: Oh yeah...I reference the function onchange in the html :-P  Thanks for pointing me elsewhere.